# How to formulate as a concept that elements of a boost::hana::Sequence all satisfy a concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, boost-hana

Assume I have the following concept:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace hana = boost::hana;
   
// this is only for consistency
template <typename S> concept hana_sequence = hana::Sequence<S>::value;

template <typename T> concept callable_with_int = requires(T&& t, int i) { t(i); };
```

I would like to define functions that work on `hana_sequence`s whose elements all satisfy this concept, like e.g.:

```cpp
void applyCallable(const sequence_of_callables auto& ha, int i)
{
  hana::for_each(ha, [&] (auto e) {std::cerr<<"inside apply – "; e(i);});
}

int main()
{
  applyCallable(hana::make_tuple(
    [] (int i) {std::cerr<<"inside lambda0 "<<2*i<<"!\n";},
    [] (int i) {std::cerr<<"inside lambda1 "<<i<<"!\n";}/*,
    [] () {std::cerr<<"inside lambda2!\n";}*/ // this would spoil compilation, as expected
  ),4);
}
```

My problem is how to define `sequence_of_callables` as a C++20 concept. After some tribulations, I came up with the following solution:

```cpp
// spurious helper needed?
template <typename T> constexpr bool sequenceOfCallablesHelper = false;

template <typename... T> constexpr bool sequenceOfCallablesHelper<hana::tuple<T...>>
  = hana::fold(hana::tuple_t<T...>, true, [] (bool s, auto element) {
    return s && callable_with_int<typename decltype(element)::type>;});

template <typename S>
concept sequence_of_callables = ( hana_sequence<S> && sequenceOfCallablesHelper<S> );
```

This works as expected, but the need for the helper and its specialization is a bit ugly.

Can this be done more directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first use `hana::transform` to convert `S` from `hana::tuple<T...>` to `hana::tuple<hana::type<T>...>`, and then use `hana::all_of` to check whether each type satisfies the `callable_with_int` concept:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

// this is only for consistency
template <typename S> 
concept hana_sequence = hana::Sequence<S>::value;

template <typename T> 
concept callable_with_int = requires(T&& t, int i) { t(i); };

template <typename S>
concept sequence_of_callables = hana_sequence<S> && 
  !!hana::all_of(
    decltype(hana::transform(std::declval<S>(), hana::typeid_)){},
    []<class T>(T) { return callable_with_int<typename T::type>; });
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WcY1YazzT)

Comment: Very nice, thank you! There are two points in this solution that seem a bit esoteric to me (I have tried, and it doesn’t work without them, but I could do with some explanation :). (1) why the `!!` in front of `hana::all_of`, and (2) why the `decltype` around `hana::transform`?

Comment: @HyperBoar (1). use `!!` to convert the return type of `hana::all_of` from `int` to `bool`, since the constraint must be `bool` type. (2). use `decltype` to get the return type of `hana::transform`, which is `hana::tuple<hana::type<T>...>`, then use `{}` to default-construct it on the fly and pass it into `hana::all_of`.

Comment: Ad (2): but why can’t we just use the return value of hana::transform directly instead of a default-constructed decltype of it? I remember trying to use std::declval with hana algorithms when I started with hana, and running into `__declval_protector`-related compilation errors. I was not aware of this additional `decltype` trick, and I still don’t really understand this mechanism.